# 3D building Mapbox

Tags: jquery, json, mapbox

my question to mapbox was :-"You have a great feature with 3D buildings. Is there any way to make just the building at the selected address in 3D and everything else around it in normal 2D?"

and i got response from mapbox:-"Our building data does not have a unique feature ID so styling them based on the feature ID might style a few buildings with the same feature ID. If you have your own building data with unique IDs, this would be possible. Otherwise, you need to implement a workaround such as Using Turf to identify the features IDs of building withing the polygon of the property data,
once approved, style the building using fill-extrusion styling spec to create the 3D effect for the building."

Now we are trying to implement above scenario. we are providing a building address and getting response as shown in below screen:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJKnT.png

I see in the mapbox documentation there is a way to create a 3D building but my question is how can we utilize our response to create a 3D building and what will be the building id in above response.
as we can see in below screen shot there is a geojson data. how can we get this geojson data which have polygon type and geometric.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwxEr.png

Answer (score 1):

To do something like this, you could try out the following steps:

1. Pass the center coordinates of the geocoder response as a variable at runtime (please note that if you want to further store this in a database, then you would need to have access to the [`mapbox.places-permanent` endpoint](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#mapboxplaces-permanent)).
2. Compare those coordinates with the polygon data in your custom building layer. You can do this comparison using [Turf](https://turfjs.org/). Alternatively, you could use the [Mapbox Tilequery API](https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/tilequery/) to query your custom building layer at that coordinate to retrieve your building's custom ID.
3. You can use [`Map#setPaintProperty`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map%23setpaintproperty) to set the [`fill-extrusion-height`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-fill-extrusion-fill-extrusion-height) for that specific id.

For your individual questions highlighted in your screenshots:

1. "floorplan" is the name of the source that you will specify yourself, and will reference below in [`Map#addLayer`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#addlayer).
2. You would not be able to generate a GeoJSON data from the geocoder -- instead, this data that will be added at runtime would be your custom building data that contains a custom ID for each building.
3. "room-extrusion" is the name of the layer that will also specify yourself. It is this layer ID that you can refer to within [`Map#setPaintProperty`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setpaintproperty).